How to use amphp with postgres transactions?
My code runs inside worker, so it executes in parallel way.
I wanted to use postgres transactions with amp/postgres library, so I wrote this code:
    public static function getNewPromocodeAndSetSentParameter(array $data, ?Cancellation $cancellation): ?string {
        $data['order'] = self::getPromocodeSort($data['promo_code_list_id']);
        $transaction = Postgres::get(Postgres::TYPE_WRITE)->connection()->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $query = $transaction->execute("WITH deleted_code AS (
             DELETE FROM promo_codes
             WHERE id = (
                 SELECT id FROM promo_codes
                 WHERE promo_code_list_id = :promo_code_list_id
                 ORDER BY id {$data['order']} LIMIT 1
             )
             RETURNING id, shop_id, promo_code_list_id, code, client_id, source_type, source_id
         )
         INSERT INTO sent_promo_codes (id, shop_id, promo_code_list_id, code, client_id, source_type, source_id, sent_date)
         SELECT id, shop_id, promo_code_list_id, code, :client_id, :source_type, :source_id, now() FROM deleted_code
         RETURNING code", $data);
            $code = $query->fetchRow();
            $transaction->commit();
            return $code['code'];
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $transaction->rollback();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

Execution is sequential, so I thought that is wont be any problems. But I started to receive this kind of errors:
The transaction has been committed or rolled back in /.../vendor/amphp/sql-common/src/ConnectionTransaction.php:321

So, I guess that another transaction tries to open in same process, while previous transaction is not closed yet. How to avoid this errors and correctly handle transactions?

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, but that error message is unhinged. It is basically "the transaction succeeded or failed" which is debateably worse than having no message at all. The message should represent one state, success or error, and should include the error message generated by the DB driver so you might have a hope of actually diagnosing the issue.

That said, there's no extra "handling" necessary for transactions other than what you're already doing. If something is deadlocking your database and blocking transactions that's something to be addressed at the DB and/or application design layer.
